# Conditional return empty fields instead true or false

Tags: php

I have the following problem.

When I try to log result it is empty field

```
 $left = $right = FALSE;
 $right = $end < ($index+1)*$arr[$index]['sec'] && $end > $index*$arr[$index]['sec'];
 $left = (($begin < ($index+1)*$arr[$index]['sec']) && ($begin >= $index*$arr[$index]['sec']));
 echo $left." - ".$right."</br>";
```

Comment: So, @Yura, how do we know values of `$end`, `$index`, `$arr`?

Comment: That's mean both variables are `false`. When you echo them, `false` is casted to empty string `''`. Read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

Comment: And... what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you echo a `false` boolean, it is shown as an empty string `''`

For debugging purpose, use `var_dump`, as it will show you the exact value of the variable. For displaying `False` and `True` strings values, use a ternary :

echo ($left ? "True" : "False")." - ".($right ? "True" : "False")."";